# How to make this table created with <div> tag responsive?

Tags: html, css, html-table

The table shown in the picture is created using `<div>` tag. I used `<div>` tag because placing the information only in a table is undesirable. Although I have tried to create the exact same table using `<table>` tag but remain unsuccessful.

**The picture of the table**

[image]

**For this table, below the Code:**

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* Global Styles */

body {
  color: #575c7a;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #515673 url(../images/background_gradient.jpg) repeat-x 0px 0px;
}
.page {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative; background-color: #fff;
}
a { color: #de9000; }
a:hover { color: #009eff; }
a.cta {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: .5em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0px 12px 0px 0px;
  background: url(../images/cta_arrow.png) no-repeat right 0px;
}
a.cta:hover { background-position: right -50px; }

nav a {
  color: #f5a06e;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .9em;
}
nav a:hover { color: #fff; }

footer { font-size: .85em; color: #9ba0bd; background-color: #515673; padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px; }

/* This class is for placing images inside the cell of the table created using <div> tag */
.image {
  width:240px; /*width of your image*/
  height:120px; /*height of your image*/
  margin:0; /* If you want no margin */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding:0; /*if your want no padding */
  float: right;

}
.image.one { background-image: url(../images/kashmir-vaishnadevi.jpg) ; }
.image.two { background-image: url(../images/kashmir-amritsar.jpg) ; }
.image.three { background-image: url(../images/leh-ladakh.jpg); }
.image.four { background-image: url(../images/haridwar-agra.jpg); }
.image.five { background-image: url(../images/shimla-manali.jpg); }
.image.six { background-image: url(../images/rajasthan.jpg); }
.clear-fix { clear: both; line-height: 1px; }

/* ***Upto this is the part of the file "screen_styles.css"*** */

/* ***Below is the part of the file "screen_layout_large.css"*** */

@charset "UTF-8";

/* Layout (global rules for all sizes) */
body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
header a.logo { display: block; position: absolute; background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #a6430a;
}

/* Layout Large Screens (default for older browsers) */

nav { top: 275px; }
nav a { margin: 12px 0px 10px 20px; }

article { padding: 60px 20px 10px 20px; }

/* I created this class to determine the position of the table in the page because the table is created with <div> tag instead of <table> tag */
.table_container {
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

/* This is a table created using <div></div> tag */

<style type="text/css">
.Table
{
  display: table;
}

.Title
{
  display: table-caption;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: larger;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #a6430a;
}

.Heading
{
  display: table-row;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.Row
{
  display: table-row;
}
.Cell
{
  display: table-cell;
  border: none;
  /*      border-width: thin; */
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}
a.cta 
{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: .5em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0px 12px 0px 0px;
  background: #a6430a;
}
</style>
/* This is a table created using <div></div> tag - End */

@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  footer { padding-left: 20px; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>My-domain.com | The Travel People</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_layout_large.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:500px)"   href="css/screen_layout_small.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width:800px)"  href="css/screen_layout_medium.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <header>
        <a class="logo" href="index.html"></a>
      </header>
      <article>
        <h1>Package Tours</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="#">Duis aute irure</a> dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </article>
      <!-- This is a table created using <div> tag -->

      <div class="Table">
        <div class="table_container">
          <div class="Title">
            <p>Tour Packages</p>
          </div>
          <div class="Heading">
            <div class="Cell">
              <p>Kashmir - Vaisnodevi</p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
              <p>Kashmir - Vaisnodevi - Amritsar</p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
              <p>Leh - Ladakh</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">
              <div class="image one"></div>
              <p>Duration: 13 Days<br>
                Total Cost: 14,000/-<br>
                Starting Date 1: 7th September, 2016<br>
                Starting Date 2: 16th September, 2016</p>
              <p><a class="cta" href="">Register Here</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
              <div class="image two"></div>
              <p>Duration: 15 Days<br>
                Total Cost: 15,500/-<br>
                Starting Date 1: 7th September, 2016<br>
                Starting Date 2: 16th September, 2016</p>
              <p><a class="cta" href="">Register Here</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
              <div class="image three"></div>
              <p>Duration: 9 Days<br>
                Total Cost: 21,000/-<br>
                Starting Date 1: Would be announced<br>
                Starting Date 2: Would be announced</p>
              <p><a class="cta" href="">Register Here</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Table">
          <div class="table_container">
            <div class="Heading">
              <div class="Cell">
                <p>Haridwar - Mussoorie - Delhi - Agra</p>
              </div>
              <div class="Cell">
                <p>Shimla - Kullu - Manali</p>
              </div>
              <div class="Cell">
                <p>Rajasthan</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
              <div class="Cell">
                <div class="image four"></div>
                <p>Duration: 11 Days<br>
                  Total Cost: 10,500/-<br>
                  Starting Date 1: 7th September, 2016<br>
                  Starting Date 2: 16th September, 2016<br>
                  Starting Date 3: 22nd December, 2016</p>
                <p><a class="cta" href="">Register Here</a></p>
              </div>
              <div class="Cell">
                <div class="image five"></div>
                <p>Duration: 11 Days<br>
                  Total Cost: 11,500/-<br>
                  Starting Date: 8th September, 2016</p>
                <p><a class="cta" href="">Register Here</a></p>
              </div>
              <div class="Cell">
                <div class="image six"></div>
                <p>Duration: 15 Days<br>
                  Total Cost: 15,500/-<br>
                  Journey Starts: 7th September, 2016<br>
                  Starting Date 1: 17th September, 2016<br>
                  Starting Date 2: 18th December, 2016</p>
                <p><a class="cta" href="">Register Here</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>          
          <div class="clear-fix"></div>
          <nav>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
            <a href="services.html">Services</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
          </nav>
          <footer>
            &copy; My Company
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I gave here almost the full codes of the two CSS files, namely 'screen_styles.css' and 'screen_layout_large.css' because if someone wants to recreate them for understanding, then it would not be a problem. I have two more CSS files for medium and small screen devices, but I think, if this problem be solved then, those two files might not give me any problem.

I tried to create the same thing with `<table>` tag, but could not. This is the desired layout and I can't afford to change this design (looks), if not be impossible.

Comment: It would be simple to make the exact view if you use bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

belive me it will require lot of efforts. and as you add stuff the problem will grow.

have you tried using bootstrap ? 
that will take some of your time but will help you get a good page.

here are some things you could apply from bootstrap :

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_images.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_jumbotron_header.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_cards.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tables.asp

try this things , i am sure you will love them